# How to customize initial config for typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to customize initial config created by the command:

```
tsc --init
```

so that it automatically populates the `tsconfig.json` file with desired options?

Or maybe there is a better way to automatically create a typescript configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

You probably know this, but in any case. You can pass along what parameters you want set like so:

```
  $ tsc --init --experimentalDecorators
        --moduleResolution node --target ES5
        --sourceMap --module system --removeComments
```